# Table of Contents chapter number width

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

I am using the `tocloft` package to design my table of contents. I know how to set the width of the chapter numbers in the toc using

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
```

However this sets a fixed width of `2em` for all chapter numbers. Some chapter numbers need more space than others - .e.g. XVII vs V. Is there a way to set the width to dynamically include the width of the chapter number followed by one space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this instance you're most likely interested in adjusting the number widths of *all* sectional units in the ToC, since they are usually set hierarchically. As such, a simple redefinition of the `\numberline` macro suffices:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~\@cftasnumb%
}
\makeatother
```

The above removes the former `\hb@xt@\@tempdima{...}` construction, which sets the number inside a fixed-width box, left-aligned. In fact, the original definition made by [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) is:

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
```

Here's a minimal working example showing the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum~\@cftasnumb%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\setcounter{chapter}{122}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\setcounter{chapter}{1233}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\setcounter{chapter}{12344}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Since the original definition left a "dynamic" gap between the number and the title, I've forced it to be `~` in my example. You can modify that to whatever length you're interested in (`\quad`, `\hspace*{2em}`, ...).

Note that this modification has to be inserted *before* calling `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with the page number width (`\@tocrmarg` and `\@pnumwidth`)?